# Calculation of \$V_o/V_i\$

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc

I know this might be a bit too specific of a question, but I have trouble calculating \$V_o/V_i\$ in the given scheme.

I was given a BJT-transistor and had to find an equivalent AC-scheme (i.e. eliminating conductors and DC sources).

Now, I am asked to calculate \$V_o/V_i\$ as seen in the image.

Can anyone give some tricks where to start etc. and/or perhaps give a solution? There are no numerical values, so the solution should be in 'symbolic' form. The part which confuses me is the 'current controlled current source' and the resistor \$R_B\$ (more precise, how to bring it in to account).

[image]

Comment: Where's i_B in the circuit?

Comment: Between the top two left points, left to right (is that clear, else I'll make a new picture)

Comment: The equivalent diagram represents one of the classical BJT amplifier schemes: Common emitter with voltage controlled current feedback (Resistor RB). The calculation would not too complicated in case RB>> Rc||Rl. However, without this simplification, it would be rather involved.

Comment: The exercise states "Let's assume the transistor is correctly set up with \$V_{cc}, R_b, R_c \$ . Not really sure what that's supposed to mean.. ( \$V_{cc}\$ obviously left out because this is the AC-equivalent.)

Comment: R_B is a feedback resistor. I remember generally how to solve these problems, but haven't done it in ages. You start by opening the feedback loop. Determine the open-loop gain (gain with R_B open). Then you need to determine the feedback type and feedback factor. Then use feedback factor to calculate the closed loop gain. Wikipedia might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_feedback_amplifier

Comment: I am afraid the standard procedure (opening the feedback loop and determination of the open-loop gain)  will cause problems because RB is an important part of the open-loop gain also. More than that, due to the Miller effect, RB drastically influences the input resistance (and again the open-loop gain). The classical procedure can be applied to opamps only.

Answer (score 2):

"*Can anyone give some tricks where to start etc*"

OK - here is a rough description of my approach.

- At first calculate the gain Ao from base to collector using the known formula transconductance x resistance Rtot (total at the collector): **Ao=-gm*Rtot**. Transconductance **gm=beta/Rpi**.
- **Rtot=Rc||RL||Rbc** with Miller-resistor at the collector node **Rbc=Rb/(1-1/Ao)**, Ao negative!
- Hence: **Ao=-gm/(1/Yc)+gm/(1/YL)+gm*(1-1/Ao)/(1/Yb)**  .
  This equation must be solved for Ao (Ao appears twice!).
- As the last step, you calculate the input resistance **Rin=Rpi||Rbb** at the base node using the Miller-Theorem (at the base) with **Rbb=Rb/(1-Ao)**.
- Finally, you can compute the resulting gain **A=Ao*Rin/(Rin+Rs)**

**EDIT_1 (comment)**: Vo/Vi=Ao because Vi=V at the base node.

**EDIT_2**: Because you specifically ask for the exact role of Rb:

The classical procedure to calculate the output voltage Vo leads to a negative value (with respect to Vi) because the gain Ao is inverting. However, there is another unwanted part of Vo which is NOT inverted. This part is not yet included in my above calculation. This part of the output voltage arrives DIRECTLY at the collector node (not via the transistors collector current) and is found using the simple voltaged divider rule **Vi*Rtot/(Rtot+Rb)**. As you can see, this (positive) part disappears for Rb>>Rtot.

Answer (score 1):

The current controlled current source (CCCS) represents the amplification property of the BJT and in this case, it means that the current through this source is given as \$ \beta \cdot I_b \$ (as it is stated in the diagram, \$  I_b \$ being the BJT's base current). However, realize that \$ I_b \$ is the current flowing only through \$ R_\pi \$ (downwards - this is determined by given relation to the direction of the current through CCCS drawn in the diagram) because \$ R_B \$ is an external element (not part of the BJT)! See the **Andy** **aka**'s question "*Where's* *i* _ *B* *in* *the* *circuit?*" and the **Robin** **Haveneers**'s answer "*Between* *the* *top* *two* *left* *points,* *left* *to* *right*" - which must be wrong from the reason mentioned above.

So, this base current \$ \displaystyle I_b \$ is given as \$ \displaystyle -V_i / R_\pi \$ (I have applied the \$ \displaystyle V_i \$ polarity used in the diagram, the same later below with the \$ V_o \$ polarity).

Let's define \$ R_o = R_c || R_l \$ (just to simplify it a bit)

Then we can write:

1. For the current flowing through \$ R_B \$ (to the left; its direction is arbitrarily chosen by me):

   - \$ \displaystyle I_{R_B}=\frac{V_i-V_o}{R_B} \$.
2. For the current flowing through \$ R_o = R_c||R_l \$ (upwards and to the left, its direction is arbitrarily chosen by me again):

   - \$ \displaystyle I_{R_o} = \frac{V_o}{R_o} \$.
3. For the current flowing through the CCCS (downwards, already stated above, its direction is determined in the diagram):

   - \$ \displaystyle I_{CCCS}=\beta \cdot I_b = -\beta \cdot \frac{V_i}{R_{\pi}} = -g_m \cdot V_i \$,

the transconductance \$ g_m \$ being defined as \$ \displaystyle \frac{\beta}{R_\pi} \$.

Since according to KCL:  \$ \displaystyle I_{R_o}=I_{R_B}+I_{CCCS} \$, we obtain:

\$ \displaystyle \frac{V_o}{R_o} = \frac{V_i-V_o}{R_B} - \beta \cdot \frac{V_i}{R_{\pi}} \$,

and, after some rearrangement:

\$ \displaystyle \frac{V_o}{R_o} + \frac{V_o}{R_B} = \frac{V_i}{R_B} - \beta \cdot \frac{V_i}{R_{\pi}} \$

From here it is already very easy to express the required gain:

\$ \displaystyle A_V = \frac{V_o}{V_i} = \frac{\frac{1}{R_B} - \frac{\beta}{R_{\pi}}} {\frac{1}{R_B} + \frac{1}{R_o}} = \frac{\frac{1}{R_B} - \frac{\beta}{R_{\pi}}} {\frac{1}{R_B} + \frac{1}{R_c} + \frac{1}{R_l}} = \frac{\frac{1}{R_B} - g_m} {\frac{1}{R_B} + \frac{1}{R_c} + \frac{1}{R_l}} \$

**EDIT** (Dec 25 2018):

If we want to know the relation between \$ V_o \$ and \$ V_s \$ (as G36 mentioned in his comment), we can continue the following way:

Using KCL, we can write: \$ \displaystyle I_{R_B} = I_b + I_{R_S} \$ (with \$ I_{R_S} \$ flowing downwards; chosen by me)

Further, using the voltage polarities from the original diagram (notice the \$ V_s \$ polarity in relation to \$ V_i \$), we obtain:

\$ \displaystyle \frac{V_i - V_o}{R_B} + \frac{V_i}{R_\pi} + \frac{V_i + V_s}{R_S} = 0 \$

We already know the relation between \$ V_o \$ and \$ V_i \$ (\$ A_V \$), so it's easy to express either the "overall" gain \$\displaystyle \frac{V_o}{V_s} \$ or just the partial one \$\displaystyle \frac{V_i}{V_s} \$, substituting for either \$ V_i \$ or for \$ V_o \$ in the above equation and rearranging it to get the required voltage ratio:

1. \$ \displaystyle V_i = \frac{V_o}{A_V} \$

   \$ \displaystyle \frac{V_o}{V_s} = \frac{1}{\frac{R_S}{R_B} - \frac{1}{A_V} \cdot [1 + R_S (\frac{1}{R_B} + \frac{1}{R_\pi})]} \$
2. \$ \displaystyle V_o = {A_V}{V_i} \$

   \$ \displaystyle \frac{V_i}{V_s} = -\frac{1}{1 + R_S (\frac{1}{R_\pi} + \frac{1 - A_V}{R_B})} \$

(Notice: \$ V_s \$ is a voltage of an ideal voltage source (thus it's the *internal* voltage of it) and \$ R_S \$ evidently represents here the *internal* resistance of that source. It determines an *attitude* to the above derived formulas - I understand the only *reachable*/*accessible* voltage is \$ V_i \$ in fact.)

Comment: I suggest to write \$ R_l \$ instead of \$ R_I \$, as my guess is that \$ R_l \$ is the load's resistance. In the same line I'd suggest to use \$ R_o \$ ('o' for 'out') instead of \$ R_{tot} \$; it's shorter and me seems more to the point. Just some minor suggestions, still going through your calculations. I also assume the current \$ I_{Rb} \$ is flowing to the right, instead of to the left.

Comment: If you define \$ I_{R_{tot}} \$ upward and to the left, it should read \$ -\frac{V_o}{R_{tot}} \$. Regarding point 3.: \$ I{CCCS} \$ I'm getting confused now. Please illustrate your answer with a drawing indicating the polarities and current directions.

Comment: May I inquire your voltage polarity convention? Is the positive polarity located at the tail of the arrow? Because that would lead to \$ I_b = \frac{V_i}{R_b} \$ if \$ I_b \$ is defined downward through \$ R_\pi \$. Otherwise I think it should be that \$ I_b = - \frac{V_i}{R_b} \$. Also assuming that with 'b' (small capital) you mean the BJT's base, and with 'B' you mean the feedback resistor.

Comment: @joe electro I have made some changes according to your advice (I -> l, tot -> o), but:
1. You wrote: "_I_ _also_ _assume_ _the_ _current_ \$ I_{R_b} \$ _is_ _flowing_ _to_ _the_ _right,_ _instead_ _of_ _to_ _the_ _left._" - No, the current direction can be chosen arbitrarily, what I did. The result direction is given by its sign (if positive, then it is identical with the chosen one, if negative, then it is opposite).
(to be continued)

Comment: @joe electro (cont.)
2. You wrote: "_If_ _you_ _define_ \$ I_{R_{tot}} \$ _upward_ _and_ _to_ _the_ _left,_ _it_ _should_ _read_ \$ −\frac{V_o}{R_{tot}} \$.“ – No again, have a look at the polarity of \$ V_o  \$ in the diagram (it means \$ V_o \$ is located at the lower connection of the resistors in fact, being referenced to the higher connection of them). It is a convention that the arrow points from a point with a „higher voltage“ (or potential, if you like) to a point with a lower one.
(to be continued)

Comment: @joe electro (cont.)
However, this is **arbitrary** matter again. Btw. it is more usual, in my opinion, to choose the opposite polarity than that chosen in the diagram. I don’t understand what confuses you regarding point 3. \$ I_{CCCS} \$ is the current through the Current Controlled Current Source (CCCS) the value of which is (given in the diagram) \$ \beta \cdot I_b \$ and its direction given by the arrow in the diagram.
(to be continued)

Comment: @joe electro (cont.)
It’s a part of the BJT small-signal model. The diagram does not indicate explicitly what \$ I_b \$ exactly is (it is a „defect“) and the autor of the question even confuses people by his wrong interpretation – I explained how it MUST BE – the only possible meaning is: \$ I_b \$ is the current flowing downward through the \$ R_\pi \$!
The attitude to voltage polarities and current direction I have already explained.

Comment: (Not related but when your fractions get really tiny and your notation gets hard to read, I recommend using `\displaystyle` for your equations. It makes things appear larger. The proper syntax in order to accomplish this is `\$ \displaystyle YOUR EQUATION FOLLOWING\$`. Look at the difference: \$\frac{x}{y}\$ and \$\displaystyle \frac{x}{y}\$. It also works with other things like integration, summation, etc. anything that takes up a lot of space.)

Comment: @KingDuken  Thanks for your good advice, I have used it and it is really better. :)

Comment: @KingDuken Thanks also for the hint. I'll experiment with it.

Comment: @Eric Best I'm honoured that you followed my notational advise, but also my head starts spinning with all those arbitrary conventions, so I'll leave it with that. Maybe however I will post an answer of my own in a way that is understandable for me and can validate your outcome.

Comment: @joe electro To the "arbitrary matters" - you can arbitrarily choose voltage polarities and current directions (and indicate your choice by arrows within the diagram) in a circuit to be solved. Then you form a set of necessary equations describing the circuit. In these equations you use/reflect the chosen polarities and directions. When you substitute variables for actual values in the result formulas, the sign of the result  gives the answer what the actual polarity or direction is like. That's all. (to be cont.)

Comment: @joe electro (cont.)  Let me know what way is better understandable for you (if it's possible for you) and I'll try to do something for it (if it's possible for me :). (I also verified my results in LTspice, calculating the needed numerical results in Excel at the same time).

Comment: @EricBest There is something wrong because when I plug Rs=Rb=rpi=Rc||RL=1k  and gm=10mS the Vo/Vi = -4.5V/V which is correct. But Vo/Vs = 3V which is incorrect. And I think the problem lies in Vi=Vo/Av and because of the fact that the gain is negative Vi is also negative which is not true

Comment: @G36 Yes you are right, I am sorry, there was a typo in the result formula for Vo/Vs: the sign in front of the item 1/Av must be (-), I have already corrected it. Thanks for your notification.

Comment: @Eric Best I'm confused about the 'arrow convention', where is the positive polarity, at the head or at the tail?

Comment: @joe electro Maybe I confused you a bit in my previous comment concerning it, I am sorry, if yes. The voltage "in charge", for instance Vo, is mentioned to be at the tail and the arrow (head) points to a reference point of that voltage. There is a convention that a current (in a **load**) flows from a point with a higher potential to a point with a lower potential (from plus to minus; although electrons flow in the opposite direction, in fact). There exist a load and source orientations. (to be continued...)

Comment: @joe electro (cont.) So, if the arrow is located along a load (resistor, etc.), the corresponding current flows through the load in the direction of the arrow. However, if it is located along a source, the current flows through that source in opposite direction (because it sources that current into a connected load). In other words, the tail means the "plus" pole of that source. However, pay attention. It is true for symbolic designations. If you attach a value, say -5V, to a voltage arrow, it means this (negative) voltage is at its tail, related (referenced) to the point the arrow points to.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I'm happy I grew up in (European?) +/- conventions. :) For instance, a (ideal) voltage source is depicted as a circle (for source) with a continuous line (wire) through it from terminal to terminal, meaning it has zero internal impedance, and outside the source at the repective terminals are a + and a - sign respectively. If value of the voltage is given as negative, then the + terminal has a negative voltage (with respect to the other).

Comment: And a (ideal current source) is a circle with a line (wire) in it perpendicular to the straight line through both terminals, indicating it has zero conductivity. Then outside is an arrow indicating the direction of the current of which the value is given outside the circle. Again, only if that value is negative, the current flows in the opposite direction as to where the arrow points. Grew up with it, love it.

Answer (score 1):

Although conventions for currents and voltages are arbitrary indeed, I prefer looking at a circuit of which I 'understand' and feel familiar with the notations and polarities. 
Therefor I'd like to redraw the circuit, defining the BJT's base current as \$ i_b \$, replacing \$ R_B \$ and \$ i_B \$ with \$ R_{fb} \$, and \$ i_{fb} \$ respectively, as they pertain to feedback. In the end these choices will not change the outcome \$ \displaystyle \frac{V_o}{V_i} \$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMYG1r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With Eric Best's approach $$ i_{fb} + i_{R_o} + \beta i_b = 0 $$ hence $$ V_o / R_o + (V_o-V_i)/R_{fb} + \beta V_i/R_\pi = 0 $$

or

$$ V_o \left( \frac{1}{R_o} + \frac{1}{R_{fb}} \right) =  V_i \left( \frac{1}{R_{fb}} - \frac{\beta}{R_\pi} \right) $$

and indeed

$$ \frac{V_o}{V_i} = \displaystyle \frac{\frac{1}{R_{fb}} - \frac{\beta}{R_\pi}}{\frac{1}{R_c} + \frac{1}{R_l} + \frac{1}{R_{fb}}} $$ 
which after replacing \$ R_{fb} \$ back with \$ R_B \$ becomes 
$$ \frac{V_o}{V_i} = \displaystyle \frac{\frac{1}{R_B} - \frac{\beta}{R_\pi}}{\frac{1}{R_c} + \frac{1}{R_l} + \frac{1}{R_B}} $$ 
which is exact confirmation of Eric Best's result.

Comment: But what if you want to find Vo/Vs instead?

Comment: @joe electro Yes, very good. In my solution I was just keeping the attitude/conventions of the original question. In one of my comments I wrote "_it_ _is_ _more_ _usual,_ _in_ _my_ _opinion,_ _to_ _choose_ _the_ _opposite_ _polarity_ _than_ _that_ _chosen_ _in_ _the_ _diagram._". Your solution fully corresponds with common conventions.

Comment: @G36 See my EDIT (continuation of my original answer), where you can find my solution concerning Vo/Vs.

Answer (score 0):

Use KCL/KVL. There are only two unknown currents, so just need two meshes for KVL. The current source should not be in either of those two meshes. BTW, are you sure that \$I_B\$ does not flow through \$R_\pi\$?

Comment: I agree with Chu - the current \$ I_B \$ flows for sure only through \$ R_\pi \$ - this is the actual base, \$ R_b \$ is an external element!